# concept question about the tangent vector

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, tangent-spaces

In differential geometry a tangent vector at $p$ on smooth manifold $M$, is a $\Bbb{R}-$linear map $$v:C^\infty(M) \to \Bbb{R}$$

which satisfies the product rule $$v(fg) = v(f)g(p) + f(p)v(g)$$

---

If we consider the $C^\infty_M$ as a structure sheaf, we have the second definition a tangent vector $v$ is a $\Bbb{R}-$linear  map over the stalk $$(C^\infty_M)_p\to \Bbb{R}$$ which satisfies the product rule $v(f_pg_p) = v(f_p)g_p(p) + f_p(p)v(g_p)$

---

I want to show these two definitions are one to one correspondence.

Comment: That not very hard , I just write the post to make it clear.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: no the question makes clear when writing it down

Comment: I find it disturbing that your first definition does not use the point $p$ in any way.

Comment: Writing the Question "Corrrectly" always helps ourselves, by giving us a chance to think & look at it with a new "Perspective" !! You can answer your own question, too. Suggestion : you can take the Answer Part out of your Question & Put that Answer here.

Comment: the valid question may be the question that you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First given a $v$ in the first definition I want to find some morphism $$\tilde{v}:C^\infty_M\to \underline{\Bbb{R}}$$

on set of filtrant open subset around $p$, then it will naturally induce a map on the stalk. to do so , using the basic fact in differential geometry that $di_p : T_pU \to T_p M$ is isomorphism, therefore given $v$ in the first definition ,it will naturally induce a $v_{_{U}}:C^\infty(U) \to \Bbb{R}$ which satifies the product rule, therefore we define the morphism $\tilde{v}(U) = v_{_U}$, since taking stalk is functorial it will gives a map on the stalk as in the definition 2.

---

Conversely given a map $v'$ in the definition 2, we want to find some $v$ in the definition one, that's easy just first take  $\varphi_p:C_M^\infty(M) \to C^\infty_{M,p} $ then $v := v' \circ \varphi_p$ gives the tangent vector in the first definition

Comment: Now I wonder how you prove that $di_p$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: First use the standard bump function arguement combined with the product rule to show that two representative elements $f,g$ for the germ have the same $v(f) = v(g)$ (this already suggest the correspondence.)  The second step use the fact that local smooth function on $U$ can be extended to the whole $M$(which also uses the bump function and partition of unity). Based on these two facts we can see the isomorphism. @Arctic Char